# Can I use ON Whey Protein and P90X Recovery Formula together?

Tags: workout, protein, muscle-recovery, p90x

I'm doing [Body Beast](https://www.beachbody.com/product/fitness_programs/body-beast-workout.do). I was using [P90X Recovery Formula](https://www.beachbody.com/product/supplements/p90x_peak_performance/p90x_peak_recovery_formula.do) after workout but it's doesn't have enough protein for me to reach my goals. So I've decided to use Whey protein too. What is the best time to use it? With P90X Recovery Formula after workout or any time during the day?

Supplements I use:

- Pre-Workout: [ON Pre-Workout](http://www.optimumnutrition.com/en_US/products/gold-standard-pre-workout)
- Post-Workout: [P90X Recovery Formula](https://www.beachbody.com/product/supplements/p90x_peak_performance/p90x_peak_recovery_formula.do)
- Post-Workout: [ON Creatine Powder](http://www.optimumnutrition.com/en_US/products/creatine-powder)
- ???: [ON Whey Protein](http://www.optimumnutrition.com/en_US/products/gold-standard-whey)

Comment: Why are you taking whey protein? To hit protein macros for the day?

Comment: Yes. P90X gives only 10gr of protein. I'm not hitting the target that is set in this program

Comment: People who down voted, can you tell me why?

Comment: In that case it makes no difference when you eat your protein. As long as you get in your required amounts for the day

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While once considered essential in bodybuilding, the importance of nutrient timing has been severely downplayed in the last few years since plenty of studies fail to show significant results and the anabolic window of increased muscle protein synthesis is quite a lot longer than used to be thought. As in, it won't matter that much whether you take your protein shake immediately after training or several hours after.

So when taking whey protein, options roughly fall within these categories:

- Before your workout
- Shortly after your workout
- Later on the day after your workout

Since you're taking a pre-workout, assuming you are not in (too much of) a fasted state, I don't see that much use in taking it beforehand since digestion could interfere with comfort during the workout. Taking it shortly after would be a good option. Taking it later is no problem, but might reduce appetite for a meal following shortly after. Since powdered whey protein digests very fast but other protein sources may digest much slower I'd say you might wanna keep some time between meals and your whey shake. Also, taking it directly after a workout is an easy timing to remember so you don't accidentally forget to take it.

As for taking it along with a recovery formula, I'm not aware of any bad interactions between whey protein and anything that isn't medicine. If you get more protein, it'll just take a bit longer to digest.